# Need help in breaking of a large table for better performance and optimization

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, amazon-redshift

So I have a table which i have to break it in 3 parts.

Table 1: This will be daily_table. This will contain data of current_date - 1 day data from the source. Also this table is truncate load on a daily basis

Table 2: This will be a 1Year_rolling table. So before truncating the daily_table the data is inserted into 1Year_rolling table. Also as name suggest it will have data of a year for e.g 1-June-2022 till 16-June-2023. Now here's a catch once we hit 1st day of the month the data from the beginning of the table i.e 1-June-2022 till 30-June-2022 will be removed and added to another table. So on the 1st of August the data in 1Year_rolling will look like 1-August-2022 till 31-July-2023.

Table 3: This will a monthend_snapshot table. This table will contain data from 2019 till 30-June-2022. Like on every 1st of the month, 1 month worth of data will be appended to this table from 1Year_rolling table.

Table 4: This will be a combined view of all the 3 above table with no duplicates.

Below there's a excel representation of the table for better understanding

[Excel screenshot for better understanding.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqImF.png)
Feel free to ask any confusion.
Thanks in advance!

I have tried many ways but not getting expected results.
Also this is in postgresSQL on Redshift.

Comment: Why don't you share the code that you tried? Some input data and some expectations would be helpful as well.

Comment: WHERE
 EXTRACT (MONTH FROM business_date) = EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SYSDATE)-1
and 
 EXTRACT (YEAR FROM business_date) = EXTRACT (YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1;
@FrankHeikens This where condition gives me last month of previous year

Comment: I would love to share DDL but there are 405 columns! I have posted the question to get help on how to handle those dates within the 3 tables!

Comment: It okay if you are not able to help me with this :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Most people solve this sort of problem by *not* splitting their data into multiple tables. Instead we do queries like this to get the date ranges we want for each use case. This gets yesterday's data.

```sql
SELECT whatever
  FROM big_table
 WHERE datestamp >= TIMESTAMP today - INTERVAL '1' DAY
   AND datestamp <  TIMESTAMP today
```

This gets last month's data.

```sql
SELECT whatever
  FROM big_table
 WHERE datestamp >= date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '1' month)
   AND datestamp <  date_trunc('month', current_date)
```

With an index on your datestamp column, this sort of operation performs well even when the table is large and contains years of data. And the complexity of migrating data from table to table simply vanishes.

Comment: Thank for you contribution Jones! But I have the data from one year ago from the 1st of the current month till current date.

Comment: Here in your code 1st of the previous month

Comment: What are your thoughts on

WHERE
 EXTRACT (MONTH FROM business_date) = EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SYSDATE)-1
and 
 EXTRACT (YEAR FROM business_date) = EXTRACT (YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1;

Comment: WHERE
 EXTRACT (MONTH FROM business_date) = EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SYSDATE)-1
and 
 EXTRACT (YEAR FROM business_date) = EXTRACT (YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1;

Comment: I tried this logic. this gives me the previous month of the system date and also the previous year of the current system date

Comment: What do you think of this?